# How do I make dynamic windows in Swing?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I have a general question. I would like to have a window containing some buttons, radio buttons, text fields and so on. So, user can do something (write text, select options and press buttons). As the result of the user activity window should change it structure/appearance some element should disappear and some appear.

How do I program such "updates"? Should I close an old window and open a new one or I can modify content of window without closing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding your components or such, calling `revalidate()` on your container will do the updates